# Convergence in probability and convergence of $\sup_{n\geq m}E(X_n\mid\mathcal{F_m}).$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X_n$ is adapted to the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n=1,2,\ldots}$, $X_n$ is positive and bounded above by some fixed $M$. If $X_n$ converges to a constant $x$ in probability, does this imply that $\sup_{n\geq m}E(X_n\mid\mathcal{F_m})\rightarrow x$ in probability as $m\rightarrow\infty$?

I think a.e. convergence gives yes. But I think this might fail for convergence in probability.  Any counterexamples?

Comment: Where do the problem come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $(A_j)_j$ a sequence of independent events such that $\mu(A_j)\to 0$ and $\sum_j\mu(A_j)=\infty$. By the Borel-Cantelli lemma, $\mu(\limsup_n A_n)=1$, hence we can find a sequence $(m_k)_k$ of integers such that $\mu\left(\bigcup_{j=m_k+1}^{m_{k+1}}A_j\right)>1/2$ for each $k$. 
We define $\mathcal F_{m_k}:=\sigma(A_j,1\leqslant j\leqslant m_{k+1})=:\mathcal F_l$ for $m_{k}\leqslant l\lt m_{k+1}$. In this way, we have

- $X_n:=\chi(A_n)\to 0$ in probability, $0\leqslant X_n\leqslant 1$ almost surely;
- let $l\in\mathbb N$; then $m_{k}\leqslant l\lt m_{k+1}$ for some integer $k$. In this case $\mathcal F_l=\sigma(A_j,k\leqslant m_{k+1})$ hence $\chi_{A_l}\in\mathcal F_l$.
- $\sup_{n\geqslant m_k}\mathbb E[X_n\mid \mathcal F_{m_k}]\geqslant 
  \chi\left(\bigcup_{j=m_k+1}^{m_{k+1}}A_j\right)$, hence $\sup_{n\geqslant m_k}\mathbb E[X_n\mid \mathcal F_{m_k}]$ does not converge to $0$ in probability.

However, if $X_n\to x$ almost surely, then 
$$\sup_{n\geqslant m}\mathbb E[|X_n-x|\mid\mathcal F_m]\leqslant\mathbb E[\sup_{n\geqslant m}|X_n-x|\mid\mathcal F_m],$$
hence 
$$\mathbb E[\sup_{n\geqslant m}\mathbb E[|X_n-x|\mid\mathcal F_m]]\leqslant \mathbb E[\sup_{n\geqslant m}|X_n-x|]$$
and this converge to $0$ using monotone convergence.

Comment: Thank you very much Davide. I am not sure about some details. Please excuse my naivete as I am not a specialist. Isn't $E[X_n\mid\mathcal F_m]$ just $E[X_n]$, when $n\geq m$, if the sequence of events $A_j$ are independent? If that is the case, then $E[X_n]$ converges to zero if $X_n$ converges to zero in probability (since $|X_n|\leq 1$). I see that $E[\sup_{n\geq m_k}X_n\mid\mathcal F_{m_k}]\geq\chi\left(\bigcup_{m_k+1}^{m_{k+1}}A_j\right),$ however.  If I am correct, the counter example would require non-independence of the sequence $X_n.$ Thanks again.

Comment: It is the case if we take $\mathcal F_m$ as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $A_1,\dots,A_m$. That's why we should enlarge $\mathcal F_m$. (there also was a typo)

Comment: I think I get it now. Should the second bullet point then read $\sup_{n\geq l}E[X_n\mid\mathcal F_l]\geq \chi\left(\bigcup_{m_{k}+1}^{m_{k+1}}A_j\right)$, for $m_{k-1}\leq l<m_k$? It seems that $(X_l,\mathcal F_l)$ is not an adapted process, though. Am I right in thinking that?

Comment: There were some confusion in the definition of $\mathcal F_l$. I've edited.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. Unfortunately my reputation isn't good enough to upvote.

Comment: As you expected, the result takes place in the case of almost sure convergence (see edit).